# shopify storefront api - Invalid value provided

Tags: graphql, shopify

I have been trying to add new line item in already created checkout using shopify storefront api.

Here is my mutation:

```
mutation letsUpdateCheckout(
  $lineItems: [CheckoutLineItemInput!]!
  $checkoutId: ID!
) {
  checkoutLineItemsAdd(lineItems: $lineItems, checkoutId: $checkoutId) {
    checkout {
      id
      lineItems(first: 1) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            title
            quantity
            variant {
              id
              sku
              title
              priceV2 {
                amount
              }
              price
              image {
                originalSrc
              }
              selectedOptions {
                name
                value
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    checkoutUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the variables:

```json
{
  "variables": {
    "input": {
      "lineItems": [
        {
          "variantId": "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC8zNjI4MTM4NzA1NzMwOA==",
          "quantity": 1
        }
      ],
      "checkoutId": "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9DaGVja291dC8xYTBlZTQ0NzhiODI3MTQwZDZkZmMzMjFkYjhlNTM5OT9rZXk9ZWJiN2Q2ODYxYmZiMjdhN2I5ZTRlOWFmYTI0NTBlNmM="
    }
  }
}
```

I have double check the values for variant Id and checkout Id, both are correct. Still getting the error like:

**Variable $lineItems of type [CheckoutLineItemInput!]! was provided invalid value
Variable $checkoutId of type ID! was provided invalid value**

Please note, I can create new checkout using the same variant Id and it is created properly so variant id looks proper to me and on creation of checkout, the checkout ID which we got in response, I am passing the same while adding a new line item to the cart.

If anyone can point the error then would be great, stucked at this point since last 2 days.

Comment: I don't know shopify API ... pass variables without wrapping into `input` 'level'/object

Comment: I am using apollo graphql library, as per their syntax, we need to wrap input parameters within "input" variable.

Comment: neither a matter of using apollo nor API requirement ... https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/checkouts/checkoutlineitemsadd ... variables structure must match variable defs (1st line), there is no `$input: someInputType` ... it could be true for some other mutation where 1st line contains $input variable and mutarion arg (2nd line) is an `input` ... https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: @xadm - thanks bro. Checked documentation and accordingly make changes in variables part. By removing the input wrapper, it works.

Comment: @Newbie can I ask where you got the `variantID` from? I am stuck on a different issue but can't seem to get the correct variant ID.